# Android Google Map Marker Reset id

Tags: java, android-maps-v2

I have a map in my Application. I added polygon with 10 markers. I'm trying to delete polygon and add new polygon with markers.

```
googleHarita.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener()

    {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick (Marker marker){
           Integer.valueOf(marker.getId().replace("m", ""))
        }
        return true;
    }

   });
```

When I want to get markerId, It returns 11. But I want to return it 0.

I cleaned map :

```
googleHarita.clear();
```

But I can not find solution.